# Please create a tag synonyms between tooltipS and tooltip

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

Please create a tag synonyms between [tooltips](/questions/tagged/tooltips) and [tooltip](/questions/tagged/tooltip).

(I don’t have enough rep in the tags to suggest one my self)

[tooltip](/questions/tagged/tooltip) has 726 questions and [tooltips](/questions/tagged/tooltips) has 144 questions with 22 questions in common.

Comment: +1; I also don't have enough rep, and came here to ask the same.